# Why did they set the shape of the float image in tensorflow cifar10 tutorial?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the [Tensorflow cifar10 tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py), in the **distorted_input** function they set the shape of the float image by doing.

```
float_image.set_shape([height, width, 3])
```

but isn't the tensor already in that shape when we loaded it distorted_image

```
distorted_image = tf.random_crop(reshaped_image, [height, width, 3])
```

Why do we need to set the shape of the tensor again before we pass it to the batch function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my opinion why it is done based on the documentation. We start with

```
distorted_image = tf.random_crop(reshaped_image, [height, width, 3])
distorted_image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(distorted_image)
distorted_image = tf.image.random_brightness(distorted_image, max_delta=63)
distorted_image = tf.image.random_contrast(distorted_image, lower=0.2, upper=1.8)
float_image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(distorted_image)
```

After [random_crop()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_crop) we know the shape of the tensor, from the documentation the shape stays the same after [random_flip_left_right()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/random_flip_left_right). But the documentation does not tell that the shape is preserved after [random_brightness()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/random_brightness) and [random_contrast()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/random_contrast). (Notice the difference between previous functions where in the return argument it was mentioned that the shape stays the same).

So as far as I understand TF does not know exactly the shape of the image afterwards and we just remind it to TF with set_shape:

> The tf.Tensor.set_shape method updates the static shape of a Tensor
>   object, and it is typically used to provide additional shape
>   information when this cannot be inferred directly.